# PHP replace params in api url pattern

Tags: php, url, printf

I have some api pattern url with params:

`http://api.example.com/{type}/{function}?{parameters}&lang={lang}&authkey={authkey}&username={username}`

What is the best way to replace params for values, maybe some magic class there is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont need to use magic for simple task like this.

Just use `str_replace` to replace "{function}" (in that "template") with some variable value.

For {parameters}, which can be multiple you may write small function that puts these parameters into one variable and makes something like this: `&param_1=value1&param_2=value2` from array like this: `$parameters = array("param_1" => "value 1", "param_2 => "value 2");`

Maybe **something like** this:

```
function parameters_to_str($params)
{
    foreach(with keys as parameter names)
    {
        $ret_val = $ret_val."&".$key."=".$value;
    }

    return $ret_val;
}

... etc.
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could str_replace in arrays.

```
$end_point = 'http://api.example.com/{type}/{function}?{parameters}&lang={lang}&authkey={authkey}&username={username}';

$tokens = array(
  '{type}',
  '{function}',
  '{lang}',
  '{authkey}',
  '{username}',
);
$values = array(
  'typeval',
  'func_name',
  'en-US',
  'abra-kadabra',
  'parrotlover',
);

if (count($tokens) == count($values)) { // just to make sure every item is present. Not necessary.
  $end_point = str_replace($tokens, $values, $end_point);
}
```